# EditText stops being focusable after changing and then reseting attributes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

In my project I have Edittexts disgused as textviews that the user can only edit after enabling an edit mode. I have set up 2 extention functions for this

```
private fun EditText.disguiseAsTextview() {
    this.isCursorVisible = false
    this.isLongClickable = false
    this.isClickable = false
    this.isFocusable = false
    this.isSelected = false
    this.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)
}

private fun EditText.breakDisguise() {
    this.isCursorVisible = true
    this.isLongClickable = true
    this.isClickable = true
    this.isFocusable = true
    this.background = editTextDrawableBackground
}
```

at first the EditText works as expected, but after disguising and undisguising, the EditText can no longer be focused on, and blinks blue, as if it were selected for a split second. dont know why this happens, as a set everything back to its default state after calling breakDisguise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `breakDisguise` method,

Replace

```
this.isFocusable = true
```

with

```
this.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
```